# how can i load csv file to postgres database using lambda function with "java/eclipse"

Tags: java, postgresql-10

I have to load my CSV file to the PostgreSQL database using AWS lambda function with the help of java code. I have tried the same with java code don't know how to use it using lambda function.

Below is the java code I used -

```
package net.codejava;
 
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
 
public class SimpleCsv2DbInserter {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";
 
        String csvFilePath = "Reviews-simple.csv";
 
        int batchSize = 20;
 
        Connection connection = null;
 
        try {
 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO review (course_name, student_name, timestamp, rating, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
 
            BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath));
            String lineText = null;
 
            int count = 0;
 
            lineReader.readLine(); // skip header line
 
            while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = lineText.split(",");
                String courseName = data[0];
                String studentName = data[1];
                String timestamp = data[2];
                String rating = data[3];
                String comment = data.length == 5 ? data[4] : "";
 
                statement.setString(1, courseName);
                statement.setString(2, studentName);
 
                Timestamp sqlTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(timestamp);
                statement.setTimestamp(3, sqlTimestamp);
 
                Float fRating = Float.parseFloat(rating);
                statement.setFloat(4, fRating);
 
                statement.setString(5, comment);
 
                statement.addBatch();
 
                if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                    statement.executeBatch();
                }
            }
 
            lineReader.close();
 
            // execute the remaining queries
            statement.executeBatch();
 
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();
 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
 
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to use Lambdas for this?

Comment: Perhaps you mean you want to use the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to process the CSV file?

Comment: Why did you tag this with Postgres when you are clearly using MySQL?

Comment: I had done changes in the above code to load data in postgressql. Just given an example what I have used for implementing the same in java but now I want same with lambda function